# Laravel incompatible foreign key error when running php artisan migrate

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a foreign key in laravel migration where it references a column on the same table. It goes something like this

```
$table->bigInteger('category_id');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
$table->foreign('parent_id')->references('category_id')->on('categories')->onDelete('set null')->onUpdate('cascade');
```

When i run `php artisan migrate:fresh` it returns the following error

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'parent_id' and referenced column 'category_id' in foreign key constraint 'categories_parent_id_foreign' are incompatible.`

From what i wrote in migration seems correct but not sure whats causing this.

Comment: `category_id` isn't unsigned, the types have to match exactly ... and I guess you don't want an auto incrementing key

Comment: @lagbox now it says its missing an index

Comment: That sounds like a different question to me. Maybe you can update your current question with more details or create a new question and close this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bigIngeger` and `unsignedBigInteger` is not compatible.

You must use the same types.

Just replace `bigInteger` with `unsingedBigInteger`;

```php
$table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
```

... And add the index for your `category_id` field.

```php
$table->index('category_id');
```

Comment: `Missing index for constraint 'categories_parent_id_foreign' in the referenced table 'categories'` new error

Comment: @Areg what a DB engine are you using?

Comment: @Areg updated the answer. You need to add the index for the field that you referencing.

Answer (score 0):

I hope following code will work.

```
$table->bigIncrements('category_id');   
$table->bigInteger('parent_id')->unsigned()->nullable();

$table->foreign('parent_id')->references('category_id')->on('categories')->onDelete('set null')->onUpdate('cascade');
```